# Negate random regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Is there a way to negate any regular expression? I'm using regular expressions to validate input on a form. I'm now trying to create a button that sanitizes my input. Is there a way so I can use the regular expression used for the validating also for stripping the invalid characters?

I'm using this regex for validation of illegal characters

```
<input data-val-regex-pattern="[^|<>:\?'\*\[\]\=%\$\+,;~&\{\}]*" type="text" />
```

When clicking on a button next to it, I'm calling this function:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var inputElement = $(this).prev();
    var regex = new RegExp(inputElement.attr('data-val-regex-pattern'), 'g');
    var value = inputElement.val();
    inputElement.val(value.replace(regex, ''));
});
```

At the moment the javascript is doing the exact opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish. I need to find a way to 'reverse' the regex.

**Edit:** I'm trying to reverse the regex in the javascript function. The regex in the `data-val-regex-pattern`-attribute is doing his job for validation.

Comment: example would be better.

Comment: As it's phrased, it seems that you'd only need to swap between `/foo/.test("bar")` and `!/foo/.test("bar")`... Can you please be more specific and maybe post some example code?

Comment: Why not remove the negation caret (`^`) if it's doing the opposite of what you want? I assume you're trying to remove punctuation?

Comment: Use `inputElement.data('valRegexPattern')` instead.

Comment: Not every "random regular expression" can be easily negated, or even be used to "strip invalid characters". However, for one that is a simple repetition of a valid-character class like yours, it is trivial.

Comment: Also, if you're validating and then just removing the characters anyway, why not just remove the characters at the start and skip the "invalid character" validation?

Comment: @hjpotter92: Is that vanilla JavaScript or jQuery? I can only seem to find the jQuery `.data()` method.

Answer (score 2):

To find the invalid characters, just take the `^` off from your regex. The carret is the negative of everything that is inside the brackets.

```
data-val-regex-pattern="[|<>:\?'\*\[\]\=%\$\+,;~&\{\}]*"
```

This will return the undesired characters so you can replace them.

Also, as you want to take off a lot of non-word characters, you could try a simpler regex. If you want only word characters and spaces, you could use something like this:

```
data-val-regex-pattern="[\W\S]*"
```

Comment: Explaaaaaain. :) "The caret (`^`) indicates a negative match when in square brackets; thus, you are selecting anything that is *not* in the set."

Comment: Actually I'm trying to find a general function that can reverse any regular expression. The expression in the attribute needs to stay.

Comment: @Thijs: That isn't possible, unfortunately. There is no generic "reversal" function for RegEx -- especially since what you mean by "reversal" can change.

Comment: @CaseyFalk I have added an answer that attempts to deal with the general case.  Negative lookahead takes you part of the way.  And all the way in some cases.

Comment: @Taemyr: *"Part of the way"* and *"in some cases."* While negative look-aheads can help and often seem to be accurate, there is not "a general function that can reverse ***any*** regular expression," as OP is requesting. That's all I'm saying. Sure, one may exist for his problem, but not for ***all*** expressions.

Comment: @Thijs, maybe you should change your validation code, if you're doing this procedure a lot. I think it would be simpler than having to "reverse" the regex. In your validation you simply tell the input not valid when you find any of the invalid characters. It's better than having to reverse a regex, and less prone to errors.

Comment: @MauricioMoraes: That's a good idea! I think I will go that way.

Comment: @CaseyFalk For testing *if* a match exists, negative lookahead gets all cases.  (Except maybe if the original regexp contains lookahead/lookbehind - in which case I am unsure about how nested lookaheads and lookbehinds are implemented).  `^(?!.*(R1))` will match exaxtly those strings that does not have any substring matching `R1`

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is to the general question of negating a regular expression.  In your specific case you just need to negate a character group, or more precisely remove the negation of a character group - which is detailed in other answers.

Regular languages – those consisting of all strings entirely by matched some RE – are in fact closed under negation: there *is* another RE which matches exactly those strings the original RE does not. It is however not trivial to construct, which perhaps explains why RE implementations often do not offer a negation operator.

However the Javascript regexp language has extensions that make it more expressive than regular languages; in particular there is the construct of negative lookahead.

If `R1` is a regexp then

```
^(?!.*(R1))
```

matches precisely the strings that does not contain a match for R1.

And

```
^(?!R1$)
```

matches precisely the strings where the whole string is not a match for R1.

Ie. negation.

For rewriting any substring not matching a given regexp, the above is insufficient.  One would have to do something like

```
((?!R1).)*
```

Which would catch any substring not containing a subsubstring that matches `R1`. - But consideration of the edge cases show that this does not quite do what we are after.  For example `((?!ab).)*` matches "b" in "ab", because "ab" is not a substring of "b".

One can cheat, and make your regexp like;

```
(.*)(R1|$)
```

And rewrite to `T1$2`

Where `T1` is the target string you want to rewrite to.

This should rewrite any portion of the string not matching `R1` to `T1`.  However I would be very careful about any edge cases for this.  So much so that it might be better to write the regexp from scratch rather than trying a general approach.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will only work on regular expressions of the type 'do not use the following characters'? I was trying to find something that works for all regular expressions. Thanks for showing the negative lookahead, I didn't knew that technique.

Comment: @Thijs No this is for general regexp (or at least regexps without lookahead/lookbehind).  Also note that I have expanded my answer for the rewriting part.

Comment: @Thijs However note that it's not independent on what you mean by negating the regexp.  The `((?!R1).)` will perfectly match any substring not containing a match for R1 as a substring - The problem is that this is almost certainly not what one is after.

Comment: Why do you say "regular languages are not closed under negation" when [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties) says "The regular languages are closed under .. the set theoretic Boolean operations: union .., intersection .., and complement ..."? I intend to attempt to clarify this if you do not, but perhaps you could do a better job, knowing what you meant.

Comment: Do you really need to delete the entire answer? It is the only one which tries to do what the OP wants! (The others just say how to negate a very specific RE.) I’d have thought you could just amend your statement about regular languages, e.g. they are closed under complement, but RE implementations often extend the concept (which may destroy the closure property), and seldom (never?) offer an explicit negation operation. Possibly also something specific about the Javascript implementation.

Comment: @PJTraill I don't really need to delete the answer.  However stating that regexp is closed under negation without showing how to negate the regexp is not good.  Implementing the complement of a regexp as a pure regular expression would, if I where to do so, involve translating the regexp to a NFA, translating that NFA to a DFA.  Taking the complement of the DFA.  Translating this DFA back into regexp.  And this still leaves the problem that OP is not quite after the negation, for example every zero length substring would be a complement to the regexp in OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your reges is as so:

```
[^|<>:\?'\*\[\]\=%\$\+,;~&\{\}]*
```

That means, it matches any non-invalid character multiple times.

Then you replace this for empty, so you leave only the bad characters.

Try this instead, without the negation (hat moved somewhere else):

```
[|^<>:\?'\*\[\]\=%\$\+,;~&\{\}]*
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the regex in the data-attribute. I'm trying to find a general negateRegex(regex) that will works on serveral regex'es